# Zombicide Green Horde tile 12V: Is the salad field made up of 1 or 2 zones?

Tags: zombicide

Rules say: "On a street, a Zone is the area between 2 linear markings". However for the salad field, for me it's not clear to see whether there is a linear marking in the middle.

[image]

Comment: Having only played the original Zombicide, I think the divider line here is the building (shed) and the outdoor area. These would be marked as 2 different zones. I don't have a definite source on this, so I won't post it as an answer.

Comment: My question only is regarding the salad area. Is it divided into two square salad zones or is it only one big salad zone?